# How to create a Pixel_8 buffer in swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, accelerate-framework

I'm trying to convert objective-c code in swift, and I'm completely blocked looking for a way to get a `Pixel_8` buffer (that I'd normally create using `calloc` in objective-c) in swift.

Here is an example in Objective-c... how does it convert to swift?

```
Pixel_8 *buffer = (Pixel_8 *)calloc(width*height, sizeof(Pixel_8));
```

Comment: did you trying with this way `var buffer: Pixel_8? = (calloc(width * height, MemoryLayout<Pixel_8>.size) as? Pixel_8)`  or `var buffer = (calloc(width * height, sizeof(Pixel_8)) as! Pixel_8)
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `calloc()` in Swift, but you have to "bind" the raw
pointer to the wanted type:

```
let buffer = calloc(width * height, MemoryLayout<Pixel_8>.stride).assumingMemoryBound(to: Pixel_8.self)

// Use buffer ...

free(buffer)
```

Alternatively:

```
let buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel_8>.allocate(capacity: width * height)
buffer.initialize(to: 0, count: width * height)

// Use buffer ...

buffer.deinitialize()
buffer.deallocate(capacity: width * height)
```

But the most simple solution would be to allocate a Swift array:

```
var buffer = [Pixel_8](repeating: 0, count: width * height)
```

which is memory-managed automatically. You can pass `buffer` to 
any function expecting a `UnsafePointer<Pixel_8>`, or 
pass `&buffer` to any function expecting a `UnsafeMutablePointer<Pixel_8>`.

Answer (score 0):

Trying with this way

**Declaration**

```
 typealias Pixel_8 = UInt8
```

**swift3**

```
var buffer: Pixel_8? = (calloc(width * height, MemoryLayout<Pixel_8>.size) as? Pixel_8)
```

**swift2**

```
  var buffer = (calloc(width * height, sizeof(Pixel_8)) as! Pixel_8)
```

[Apple API reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/accelerate/pixel_8)

Comment: Pixel_8 is already defined. Anyway, I'm getting this error: `Cannot convert value of type Pixel_8? to the expected argument type UnsafeMutableRowPointer!`